Python code for deleting multiple SQL records taking too long: how to optimize?
My delete_ids variable contains 8,000 unique conversation IDs. I am trying to delete these 8,000 conversation IDs from my SQL table one at a time in a loop. I cannot delete all 8,000 IDs at once because some of them may not be valid conversation IDs; they might be something else. Therefore, I have written a try-except block to skip IDs that cannot be deleted or cause errors. However, this process is taking almost 40 minutes. The count in my delete_ids list can vary, going up or down. Is there a more efficient way to improve the performance of my code?
failed_deletions = []

if len(matching_records_sql) < len(matching_records_df):
    delete_ids = matching_records_sql['CONVERSATIONID'].tolist()
    if delete_ids: 
        delete_query = "DELETE FROM MY_TABLE WHERE CONVERSATIONID = ?"
        
        conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                              r'SERVER=My_Server_Name;'
                              r'DATABASE=Database_Name;'
                              r'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        
        for id in delete_ids:
            try:
                cursor.execute(delete_query, (id,))
                conn.commit()
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Failed to delete CONVERSATIONID {id}: {e}")
                failed_deletions.append(id)
        
        #conn.close()
        print('List of deleted ids from SQL table: ', [id for id in delete_ids if id not in failed_deletions])
        print('List of IDs that failed to delete: ', failed_deletions)
    else:
        print('No IDs to delete.')
else:
    print('matching_records_sql is not < matching_records_df')


Why not WHERE CONVERSATIONID IN (all your ids)?

Hint: You may not need to .commit() inside the loop, you could just let your deletions accumulate within the transaction and then .commit() once at the end.

In this case, you are performing 8000 individually and commiting after each one. This generates 8000 individual commits.
The ideal way you would loop through the CONVERSATIONID and filter them appropriately (checking constraint or something else). At this point you know which CONVERSATIONID will be deleted or not.
Then you delete them all at once, with a DELETE FROM MY_TABLE WHERE CONVERSATIONID IN ?
Also, depending on FK checks and indexes it could improve your query but just moving from individual queries to an aggregated one you should see massive performance improvements.
EDIT: After a bit of consideration, I've decided to expand this answer.
If you don't want to filter the conversations before, you could just issue a full DELETE FROM MY_TABLE WHERE CONVERSARTIONID IN ? with the full list. The un-deletable records will be kept on the table, so you could retrieve the full list of undeleted records by SELECT CONVERSATIONID FROM MY_TABLE WHERE CONVERSATIONID IN ?; this should return the "undeletable" records, on a very similar way that your current code is doing (although on a batch operation in a single commit, which should be much faster)

If your SQL table is large, then it would make more sense to let the DB server to perform this delete operation in a single transaction - this would be very efficient.
Demonstration:
# create DF with ID's that need to be deleted
delete_ids_df  = matching_records_sql[["CONVERSATIONID"]]

# create a temporary table containing ID's which need to be deleted
delete_ids_df.to_sql("temp_ids", conn, if_exists="replace")

sql = "select CONVERSATIONID from temp_ids where CONVERSATIONID in (select CONVERSATIONID from MY_TABLE)"
# these ID's will be deleted
existing_ids = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)

sql = "delete from MY_TABLE where CONVERSATIONID in (select CONVERSATIONID from temp_ids)"
cursor.execute(sql)



If you expect some errors when deleting rows you still can delete in batches to avoid long execution. And a batch can't be deleted try to delete rows one by one.
import pyodbc

multiple_delete_query = "DELETE FROM MY_TABLE WHERE CONVERSATIONID IN ?"
delete_query = "DELETE FROM MY_TABLE WHERE CONVERSATIONID = ?"

def batch_delete(cursor, delete_query, ids_batch):
    failed_deletions = []

    try:
        cursor.execute(multiple_delete_query, [(id,) for id in ids_batch])
        cursor.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to delete batch: {e}")
        for id in ids_batch:
            try:
                cursor.execute(delete_query, (id,))
                cursor.commit()
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Failed to delete CONVERSATIONID {id}: {e}")
                failed_deletions.append(id)
     return failed_deletions
     

def delete():
    failed_deletions = []
    if len(matching_records_sql) < len(matching_records_df):
        delete_ids = matching_records_sql['CONVERSATIONID'].tolist()
        if delete_ids:         
            conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                                  r'SERVER=My_Server_Name;'
                                  r'DATABASE=Database_Name;'
                                  r'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
            cursor = conn.cursor()
    
            batch_size = 100  # <= Change batch size if needed
            for i in range(0, len(delete_ids), batch_size):
                ids_batch = delete_ids[i:i+batch_size]
                failed_deletions += batch_delete(cursor, ids_batch)
    
            conn.close()
            print('List of deleted ids from SQL table: ', [id for id in delete_ids if id not in failed_deletions])
            print('List of IDs that failed to delete: ', failed_deletions)
        else:
            print('No IDs to delete.')
    else:
        print('matching_records_sql is not < matching_records_df')

